# Spinner value is changed When scrolling spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I'm using Spinner with custom adapter.
the issue is When I scrolling the spinner, spinner's values is changed other position's value, like this screenshot : 
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxHhy.jpg)

My layout not contains ListView.
I don't know why this happens. this is my codes :

```
#TeamScreen.java#

                public class TeamScreen extends Fragment
            {
                TeamListAdapter teamListAdapter;
                List<HashMap<String, String>> teamList;
                Spinner spin_list ;

                // instance
                private static TeamScreen instance;
                public static TeamScreen getInstance()
                {
                    if(instance == null) instance = new TeamScreen();
                    return instance;
                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
                {
                    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_team, container, false);
                    spin_list = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spin_list);
                    refreshTeamList();

                    return v;
                }



                public void refreshTeamList()
                {
                String sql = "SELECT LIST_NO     " +
                         "         , LIST_NAME   " +
                         "         , IMG0        " +
                         "         , IMG1        " +    // IMG0 ~ IMG5 is number, between 0 and 5
                         "         , IMG2        " +
                         "         , IMG3        " +
                         "         , IMG4        " +
                         "         , IMG5        " +
                         "      FROM TABLE_TEST";

                // DBMng.selectQuerys will return result for the above query, as List<HashMap<String, String>>
                    teamList = DBMng.selectQuerys(getActivity(), sql, null);
                    if(teamList != null)
                    {
                            teamListAdapter = new TeamListAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, teamList);
                            spin_list.setAdapter(teamListAdapter);
                            teamListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }

            }




#TeamListAdapter.java#
                public class TeamListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>
            {

                Context ctx;
                ListList<HashMap<String, String>> objects;
                LayoutInflater inflater;
                ViewHolder vh;

                public TeamListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<HashMap<String, String>> objects)
                {
                    super(context, resource, objects);
                    this.ctx = context;
                    this.objects = objects;
                    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                }

                @Override
                public View getDropDownView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent)
                {
                    return getCustomView(position, v, parent);
                }


                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent)
                {
                    return getCustomView(position, v, parent);
                }

                public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
                {

                    View row = convertView;

                    if(row == null)
                    {
                        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_team, parent, false);
                        vh = new ViewHolder(row);
                        row.setTag(vh);
                    }
                    else vh = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();


                    HashMap<String, String> item = objects.get(position);

                    vh.tv_name.setText(item.get("LIST_NAME"));

                    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
                    {
                        if(!item.getString("IMG" + i).trim().equals(""))
                        {
                    // my image file name likes "test0.png", "test1.png", .... "test5.png" 
                            int imgId = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(
                                    "test" + item.get("IMG" + i),
                                    "drawable",
                                    ctx.getPackageName());

                            if(imgId != 0) Glide.with(ctx).load(imgId).into(vh.imgs[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    return row;
                }

                class ViewHolder
                {
                    ImageView imgs[];
                    TextView  tv_name;

                    public ViewHolder(View v)
                    {
                        imgs = new ImageView[6];
                        imgs[0] = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_team0);
                        imgs[1]=  (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_team1);
                        imgs[2] = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_team2);
                        imgs[3] = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_team3);
                        imgs[4] = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_team4);
                        imgs[5] = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_team5);
                        tv_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
                    }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Cause you are using `convertView` ,item 9 will be the same as item 1.For this issue ,you can do like this :

  ```
               for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
                      if(!item.getString("IMG" + i).trim().equals(""))
                      {
                         ...
                       //Load image using Glide if has imgId
                       Glide.with(ctx).load(imgId).into(vh.imgs[i]);

                      }else{
                      //do something you can clear the image from the convertView and set the default image.
                         vh.imgs[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.defaultImage);
                      }
                  }
  ```